# Scatter plot with arrows using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a scatter plot in matplotlib with arrows coming out of the points to indicate upper limits. To this end I've done the following,

```
arrow = u'$\u2193$'
ax.plot(x, y, linestyle='none', markersize=20, marker=arrow)
ax.plot(x, y, linestyle='none', markersize=10, marker='o')
```

However, I'm not totally satisfied with the results -

[image: This is the result]

I'd like the arrows to come out of the middle of the points. So that point+arrow looks more like a single shape. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try combining a scatter plot with [arrows](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this with `quiver`.  It takes position and direction data to make plots full of arrows.  But they'll start at the x,y rather than being centered (as you found in plot)

```
x=[4.0,7.0,4.5]
y=[3.0,1.0,5.5]
u=[0,0,0]
v=[1,1,1]
fig, ax = subplots()
ax.quiver(x,y,u,v)
ax.scatter(x,y,color='k')
ax.axis([0,10,0,10])
```

Comment: actually, there is a kwarg (`pivot_point`?) that controls where the arrow rotates around.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the size of a quiver without scaling it some property of the plot? I'd like bigger arrows than the default but in the documentation I only see relative scaling for the size of the arrows.

Comment: Sorry, not sure that i'm following you. the argument `scale=` will change the length of all of the arrows.  `width=` will make them heavier, but not longer.  Are neither of those what you're after?

Comment: I was misreading the documentation, yes, scale is what I was looking for. Thanks.